# XML attribute double value

Tags: java, xml, dbunit

I'm trying to use **DBUnit** to test my repository service.
I have this xml that show the expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <product id="1" description="Printer" price="75.0" />
</dataset>
```

---

```
id= String , description = String , price = double.
```

The problem is I'm used to [json](/questions/tagged/json), not [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) so I don't know how to format an attribute as type double.

I tried: `price="75.0" , price=75.0 , price=75`

I cannot cast it to double afterwards because I let DBUnit do the parsing:

```
IDataSet expectedDataset = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(expectedDataSetFile);
```

Currently, my assertion fails because of this problem, using the debugger I see the data is put in correctly.

---

### Screenshot

[image: expected]
[image]

Comment: What is the code you're using to parse the XML file?

Comment: read - "I let DBUnit do the parsing" - so I have no control over this

Comment: @ the downvoters, please provide why you downvoted...

Answer (score 1):

In XML by default everything is a string. You can use an [XML Schema Definition](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xsd/) to enforce rules over your data and its structure, which would make it possible to state that the price is a double.

However, I don't know DBUnit but I would expect it to provide another easier way to state your data format.

Comment: He tried `price="75.0"` + What solution are you providing?

Comment: @YassinHajaj to add an XSD definition to its XML. Please tell me how I was unclear so I edit my answer

Comment: The answer is not unclear but what is the concrete solution you're providing here without knowing how he coded to parse the file?

Comment: I don't see the code for its xml parsing, but any standard XML parser would parse an XML without XSD as String, whereas an XML with an XSD stating the attribute is a double would be correctly parsed as Double

Comment: "he coded to parse the file" I'm pretty sure the parsing is handled by DBUnit's `new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build()`, and I'm pretty sure this function would behave as expected if an XSD was backing up the XML file

Answer (score 0):

In XML, everything is a string. You can define an attribute as a float in the schema but this will not make the parser deliver it to the application as a floating point value. It will still deliver it as a string.

When you define an attribute value as a type in XML, you are actually defining a string pattern that it must adhere to. In other words, you are saying that the string must contain a value that follows the pattern of a string representation of a floating point value. The validator will flag it as an error is the string does not match this pattern, but the parser will still deliver it as a string.

A downstream application (such as an XSLT script) may look at the schema and use the information it contains to interpret the value as a float, but the parser will not. In other words, you will need to cast it yourself.